# Issue inserting String into StringBuffer/StringBuilder with stream/parallelStream

Tags: java, java-stream, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I was trying to insert Strings into StringBuffer using foreach method of parallelStream(), created from a Set collection.
The problem is every time I execute the code, the final String (StringBuffer.toString()) has 1 less element of the total (random element every time I try).

I also change the StringBuffer to StringBuilder, the parallelStream() to stream(), but always has 1 less element.

I am using: 
- Java version: java 1.8_121
- Server: Weblogic 12.2.1.2 (I don't think this is relevant to the problem)
- Spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE (I don't think this is relevant to the problem)

NOTE: I used a Map to keep the pdfs I should sign later on the process (in another HTTP request).

```java
Map<String, ClientPdf> dataToEncript = new HashMap<>(); // pdf name it will be the key for this map (it is unique in the sql query)

List<Client> listClients = // list of clients from database
Set<ClientPdf> clientsPdf = new HashSet<>();
for (Client client : listClients) { 
    clientsPdf.add(client.clientPdf()); // clientPdf() generate a new object ClientPdf, which is similar to Client class, but with less fields (essential for the Set)
}

log.debug("Generating documents");
clientsPdf.parallelStream().forEach(pdf -> {
    // some code to generate pdf

    log.debug("Inserting pdf: {}", pdf); // this log print, for example, 27.000 lines
    dataToEncript.put(pdf.getPdfName(), pdf);
});


StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); // StringBuffer or StringBuilder, the same problem
for (ClientPdf clientPdf : dataToEncript.values()) {
    sb.append(clientPdf.getPdfName() + ";" + clientPdf.getRut() + "\n"); // appending all values of de map dataToEncript, it will append 26.669 (1 less)
}
```

Comment: Does there exist the same pdfName value but different rut value in your ClientPdf set?

Comment: No. In my country (Chile), "rut" is the unique identifier for people, so it could be a client have more than 1 pdf, but a pdf only belongs to 1 person.

Comment: OK, or could you print out the size of cliendsPdf set before you concatenate the values by StringBuffer or StringBuilder?

Comment: In clientesPdf.parallelStream().forEach() I print out all the pdf names and, for example, there are 27.000 pdfs; but when I append the names to the StringBuffer (or StringBuilder), it only appends 26.999 (1 less).
The strangest thing is that the pdf left out is different for every execution.
I think that the problem is, for a rarely strange situation, with stream()-StringBuffer (or builder) pair.

Answer (score 4):

```
clientsPdf.parallelStream().forEach(pdf -> {
    // ... 
    dataToEncript.put(pdf.getPdfName(), pdf);
});
```

`dataToEncript` is not a thread-safe data structure, so this is likely to cause ridiculous and weird bugs like the one you're observing

In general, using `forEach` is often a bad sign, and you should almost always be using a `Collector` or some other method.  For example, here you should probably use

```
clientsPdf.parallelStream()
   .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Pdf::getPdfName, pdf -> pdf));
```

to get a correct map out.

Even better, you could write

```
clientsPdf.parallelStream()
    .map(clientPdf -> clientPdf.getPdfName() + ";" + clientPdf.getRut() + "\n")
    .collect(Collectors.joining())
```

to get the final `String` out without any manual management of `StringBuffer` or the like.

Comment: Thank you very much Louis for your answer, but I have a few questions:
- Why do you say that is bad sign using a forEach statement in this case?
- About the dataToEncript that is not thread-safe, I also changed the parallelStream() to simple stream() and this weird bug still appeard; I don't know if you have seen a problem like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Because `HashMap` is **not thread-safe** as Wasserman mentioned above.
It may cause an inconsistency in the state of `HashMap` if multiple threads are accessing the same object and try to modify its structure.

Therefore, `HashTable`, `SynchronizedMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` are introduced to use `HashMap` in multi-thread environment (such as `parallelStream()`).

You can simply rewrite the first row of your code as follows:

```
Map<String, ClientPdf> dataToEncript = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
```

Now, you are supposed to get the correct result after rerunning your program.

BTW, both `HashTable` and `SynchronizedMap` are not good in performance, you can use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead to overcome this issue.

Good luck!